# Shortcut/Action on Siri Watch Face with independent WatchOS app

Tags: swift, xcode, watchos, sirikit

I'm relatively new to making apps, and even newer to independent watch apps. As training, I'm making a watch app that I can use to log my water intake throughout the day. I've created a new intent definition file (see image 1) on which I've checked the marks for all the target memberships (the app, the WatchKit app, and the WatchKit extension). Furthermore, the target membership class is a public intent for the WatchKit extension.

When logging my water I execute the following code:

```swift
let intent = INManager.intent(drink: item)
INManager.donateShortcuts(withIntent: intent)
```

and my IntentManager looks like this:

```swift
import Foundation
import Intents

class IntentManager {
    
    func intent(drink: Drink) -> LogDrinkIntent {
        let intent = LogDrinkIntent()
        
        intent.uuid = drink.id.uuidString
        intent.name = drink.name
        intent.emoji = drink.emoji
        
        return intent
    }
    
    func donateShortcuts(withIntent intent:INIntent) {
        var relevantShortcuts: [INRelevantShortcut] = []
        
        if let relevantShortcut = defaultRelevantShortcut(withIntent: intent) {
            relevantShortcuts.append(relevantShortcut)
        }
        
        INRelevantShortcutStore.default.setRelevantShortcuts(relevantShortcuts) { (error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Failed to set relevant shortcuts: \(error))")
            } else {
                print("Relevant shortcuts set.")
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func defaultRelevantShortcut(withIntent intent: INIntent) -> INRelevantShortcut? {
        if let shortcut = INShortcut(intent: intent) {
            let relevantShortcut = INRelevantShortcut(shortcut: shortcut)
            relevantShortcut.shortcutRole = .action
            
            let template = INDefaultCardTemplate(title: "Log Drink")
            relevantShortcut.watchTemplate = template

            print("Returning relevant shortcut.")
            
            return relevantShortcut
        }
        
        return nil
    }
}
```

When logging a drink the confirmation `Returning relevant shortcut.` and `Relevant shortcuts set.` are printed. However, the Siri watch face doesn't update to include a link to my action. I got the code for the `IntentManager` from [this Medium article](https://medium.com/@abdul.i.aljebouri/relevant-shortcuts-on-siri-watch-face-b1a5ed946d19).

I really appreciate your time and help. I've had a hard time trying to find *any* details about this functionality and Apple's documentation is imo inferior. Thank you! If you need more details or such, feel free to ask.

Image 1
[image: Intent definition file]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's saddle the horse from behind: Generally speaking, you want to make use of [Soup Chef](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/soup_chef_accelerating_app_interactions_with_shortcuts). Now you can categorize Siri suggestions into two sub-groups, being [donated shortcuts](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/donating_shortcuts) and [relevant shortcuts](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/relevant_shortcuts_for_the_siri_watch_face).

In your specific example of a *"water intake" logging app*, you should work with donating the `INIntent` to `INIteraction`. The reason for that is quite simple: Your suggestion is due to an action a user has committed within your application, not based upon plainly relevance, thus your passage about `INRelevantShortcutStore` isn't necessary and/or should be replaced with `INInteraction`.

To re-phrase myself: The issue is that you parse `INRelevantShortcutStore` as a donation, see here:

```
func donateShortcuts(withIntent intent:INIntent) {
        var relevantShortcuts: [INRelevantShortcut] = []
        
        if let relevantShortcut = defaultRelevantShortcut(withIntent: intent) {
            relevantShortcuts.append(relevantShortcut)
        }
        
        INRelevantShortcutStore.default.setRelevantShortcuts(relevantShortcuts) { (error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Failed to set relevant shortcuts: \(error))")
            } else {
                print("Relevant shortcuts set.")
            }
        }
    }
```

... as explained above, that is not the correct usage for `INIntent` in your specific example.

I **highly suggest** to read through [Soup Chef](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/soup_chef_accelerating_app_interactions_with_shortcuts) in general as well as specifically [donating shortcuts to Siri](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/donating_shortcuts) (what you want to do!). *The documentation is very detailed and explanative!*

Comment: As you better know what your application is supposed to do, i.e. based upon timing and so forth, I wasn't able to properly compose a finished example with [donated shortcuts](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/donating_shortcuts#overview). Though the documentation is very well written and therefore I guess you won't have any problems with replacing the necessary `INIntent`.

Comment: This is great! Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I'm getting an error when donating my new INInteraction but that's for another question.